# How to change the content in real time using node js?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

Have small app (My first Node js App), where I want add changing real-time content.

For example I have a common url which have list of content link, when user click on particular link it will open its correspondence link.

I have teacher and student role in the app so if teacher open the specific content(From the common url page) then it will automatically open that content for all student who have common url.

Please give me any Idea to implement this functionality and please tell me any plugin who have same functionality for real time content change.

Comment: it is quite achievable, on receiving an click event from the server(emited by teacher) change the url of your clients as required.

Answer (score 0):

One way, probably the easiest would be to use websockets, an easily manageable choice is `socket.io` npm package. What makes websockets different from http requests is the direction of the data flow. While http is pull based, meaning that a request has to be made to the server in order to get a response, websockets - once the connection is established - are or at least can be push based, meaning that the server could push out content without having to get a request from the client. In your situation, the teacher and the studens would all have an active websocket connection with the server. When the teacher clicked on a certain view, it would push the view’s data requirements to the students without any interaction from their side and the view would update on their screens according to the pushed data.

Look into how websockets work and try to experiment with a basic `socket.io` setup.